# Error using PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, reference

I instaled for first time the powershell tools and I can create a project like power shell script, or power shell module. But I can't run it. the error when I press F5 is the following

> "No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ni una de sus dependencias. El
>   sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado"

I try to search System.Management.Automation in References inside de project

¿Any Idea?
(Another way to work with powershell if this don't go ok?)

Thanks

Comment: Does the problem shows when you run VS in admin mode? If it does, try to install Windows Management Framework v3 (and reboot).

Comment: I try to install Windows Management Framework v3 and show this message "The update does not apply to equipment"
I never run VS like a Admin. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio executing the following command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe" /admin /uninstall:58dce676-42b0-4dd6-9ee4-afbc8e582b8a

Then you install it again
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c9eb3ba8-0c59-4944-9a62-6eee37294597

source:https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/issues/253